# Detect Previous Next ID

Tags: php, pdo

I have a little script that have a Previous & Next button. 
My problem is I want to detect & place the ID in those buttons

this is the code from the pagination

```
  <body>
    <?php include_once 'data.php'; ?>
    <center>
        <ul class="pagination">
        <?php
            if($page_counter == 0){
                echo "<li><a href=?start='0' class='active'>0</a></li>";
                for($j=1; $j < $paginations; $j++) { 
                  echo "";
               }
            }else{
                echo "<a href=?start=$previous><button>Previous</button></a>"; 
                for($j=0; $j < $paginations; $j++) {
                 if($j == $page_counter) {
                    echo " ";
                 }else{
                    echo " ";
                 } 
              }if($j != $page_counter+1)
                echo "<a href=?start=$next><button>Next</button></a>"; 
            } 
        ?>
        </ul>
        </center>
```

In this part I have the ID but the problem is I can`t get it with this example  to place it into the pagination.

```
       <?php 
                foreach($result as $row) { 
                    echo '

      <div class="card"><button1>

      '. $row['notice_id'] .'

       <div class="time-left">
      <div class="dropdown1">
       ' ;
      }
      }
      else {
      echo '';
      }
      $conn->close();
      ?> 
      </div></div>
```

This is the code from data.php I think I need to place some code into for detection from the ID

```
<?php 
//include configuration file
require 'configuration.php';

$start = 0;  $per_page = 1;
$page_counter = 0;
$next = $page_counter + 1;
$previous = $page_counter - 1;

if(isset($_GET['start'])){
 $start = $_GET['start'];
 $page_counter =  $_GET['start'];
 $start = $start *  $per_page;
 $next = $page_counter + 1;
 $previous = $page_counter - 1;
}
// query to get messages from messages table
$q = "SELECT * FROM group_notice LIMIT $start, $per_page";
$query = $db->prepare($q);
$query->execute();

if($query->rowCount() > 0){
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
// count total number of rows in students table
$count_query = "SELECT * FROM group_notice";
$query = $db->prepare($count_query);
$query->execute();
$count = $query->rowCount();
// calculate the pagination number by dividing total number of rows with per page.
$paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some formulas for calculate limit and offset of results.
For example you have 100 records, and you want to paginate it into 10 records per page, and the formula is like below.

```
 // Get Page from Query String
 $page = 1;
 if(!empty($_GET["page"])){
  $page = $_GET["page"];
 }

 // Get record count
 $count_query = "SELECT * FROM group_notice";
 $query = $db->prepare($count_query);
 $query->execute();
 $count = $query->rowCount();
 $per_page = 10; // records per page
 $pages = ceil($count/$per_page); // get total page
 $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page; // get offset

 // Do something with your records
 $query = db->prepare("SELECT * FROM group_notice LIMIT ?, ?");
 $query->bind_param("ii", $start, $per_page); // you should use bind param if you use prepared statement
 $query->execute();
 if($query->rowCount() > 0){
   $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }

 if($page > 1){
  echo '<a href="?page='.$page-1.'">Prev</a>'; // Print Prev Page
 }
 for($i = 1; $i <= $pages){
  echo '<a href="?page='.$page+$i.'">'.$i.'</a>'; // Print Page Number
 }
 if($page < $pages){
  echo '<a href="?page='.$page+1.'">Next</a>'; // Print Next Page
 }
```

Hope it helps.